# Is it possible to add classes to content elements?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am developing a Wordpress theme. To display the content I use

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    the_content();
endwhile;
```

This, as you know, displays the contents as html like

```
<h1>Title<h1>
<p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

etc. Is it possible to make Wordpress add classes to these content elements or even wrap these elements like

```
<h1 class="col-sm-12">Title<h1>
<p class="col-sm-8">Lorem Ipsum</p>
```

or

```
<div class="col-sm-12">
    <h1>Title<h1>
</div>
<div class="col-sm-8">
    <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</div>
```

respectively?

Comment: I've seen some bootstrap based plugin which helps you add classes or wrap content in columns on backend while adding content.
It might help you:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/galau-ui-visual-editor/

Answer (score 0):

```
  // you can do this like this 
 <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <h1><?php the_title() ?><h1>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <?php the_content() ?>
    </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was wrapping elements that are returned by  `the_content`

Answer (score 0):

You could use "*TinyMCE advanced*" to create custom buttons that would wrap the text in a div with the classes you want. 
This [tutorial](https://www.gavick.com/blog/wordpress-tinymce-custom-buttons) might help.